# With a pandas DataFrame, how do I keep every 7th row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If my `DataFrame` has 100 rows, I want to keep every 7th one, starting with the first one.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If it is just 100 rows, you can loop then check using modulo?

Comment: I have it working with `if index % 7 != 0:` in an interation loop, but I feel like there's a better way

Comment: How about `df[::7]` or `df.loc[::7]` ..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `df` is Your dataframe, try:

```
df[::7]
```

Answer (score 1):

`HERE :`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.randint(1, 100, 100)})
df.iloc[np.arange(0, 100, 7)]
```